# Can't get Eclipse AVD NexusS 4.1 to work - Says Connect your charger?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

My AVD Nexus emulator isn't allowing me to test my android programs.  When I open it I get this message?

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html refer this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the emulator always says that or that it is charging, but it never changes. Did you "unlock" your emulator after running your program? You need to click on the lock symbol and drag it to unlock and your app should run just fine.

Comment: Thanks you can tell this is new to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change emulator **power status** use:

```
$ curl telnet://localhost:5554 <<!
power status full
quit
!
```

or

```
$ curl telnet://localhost:5554 <<!
power display
quit
!
```

to show the current status:

```
AC: online
status: Full
health: Good
present: true
capacity: 100
```

Comment: can you please clarify me, what do you mean by `localhost:5554 <<!` ?

Comment: The answer that you have posted is fine @dtmilano, but the problem is, when ever I try to run these commands on cmd.exe, the emulator crashes and the connection to the localhost will be lost.