# Android Emulator got discharged completely - running telnet power command crashing the Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Good evening friends, I am a newbie to android. My problem is, when ever I started emulator, it is showing battery as nill and the message as `connect to charger`. While I am searching for this over internet, I came across using the Telnet commands. I have used the following commands -

```
telnet localhost 5554
power capacity 100
```

This is crashing my application. Not only the `power` command, but also other commands except `help`. I have tried changing the power to 99, 70, 20, etc., nothing made difference in the output.

For this, I have tried the suggestion given in [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) article.

I also have tried solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484325/cant-get-eclipse-avd-nexuss-4-1-to-work-says-connect-your-charger#) question.

This question might look as a duplicate of already existing questions. But, I have tried all those solutions,

I have

- reinstalled eclipse
- reinstalled android-sdk
- reinstalled avd manager
- recreated existing AVD

I am using Intel Atom (x86) Emulator. The target is Android 4.3 with API level 18.

I have also followed the instructions and suggestions given over [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=39959) like changing the `hw.battery` option in  the config.ini file in `.android\avd\` folder.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that an emulator could run out of battery. For me the symbol always looks like it is charging for some reason.

Comment: I too thought the same till yesterday, this is really looking strange for me. The battery symbol in my emulator looks same as in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484325/cant-get-eclipse-avd-nexuss-4-1-to-work-says-connect-your-charger#` link. Due to this, I even could not run at least a hello world application.

Comment: Have you tried `power status full`, `power capacity 100`, and `power ac on`?

Comment: yes @323go, I have tried them, but no difference in the output.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to set the `hw.battery=yes` in the AVD config.ini file as described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17467342/2232812

> 1. Go to your Android Virtual Devices folder. On Windows 7 it's this folder for example:
>      `C:\Users\{yourUserName}\.android\avd\{yourAVDName}.avd`
> 2. Open the **config.ini** file
> 3. Set the battery option to yes: `hw.battery=yes`
> 4. **Restart** your **Virtual Device** and be happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Atlast, I was able to run the emulator exactly how I wanted. I checked the list of devices using `adb devices`. At first, I got nothing tin the list. Then I run this command `adb connect <ip address of the VirtualMachine>`. Then, I opened `Run configurations`. I saw the Virtual device in the list. I selected it and started running my application.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in emulator when using telnet, and by the way this is OS independent issue, it may appears in Microsoft Windows, or in Linux.
see the issue page:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39959

I tried many solutions, but all failed, however when I delete the AVD and create new one the problem disappeared.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

I use Window 7 and i had the same problem with the emulator. When i oped the config.ini file i had to put the backspace character in each line because all the file content was in one single line like this:

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1hw.dPad=nohw.lcd.density=240hw.cpu.arch=armhw.device.hash=499058361
```

..... and so on

after formatting it looks like this:

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
hw.dPad=no
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.device.hash=499058361
```

That works for me. Now the emulator accepts pretty much all the commands.